# How do I Unit Test a method that returns IEnumerable

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Please see the code below:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Numbers()
{
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;
    yield return 4;
    yield return 5;
}
```

and the unit test below:

```
public void GetNumbers()
{
    ClassToTest c = new ClassToTest();
    var expected = 
    var actual = c.Numbers();
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

I need help populating the line that starts: `var expected`

Do I have to cast to a list for the assert to work.  Please notice that order is important i.e. the two collections must have numbers in the order of: 1,2,3,4,5.

Please note the code above is not a real test.  I have used it to explain my problem.

Comment: It should be any collection whose elements are in the same order and equal to the elements in the actual collection, right? So anything like an array or list should do, or?

Comment: IEnumerable<int> ins = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5};

Comment: You could use a `List<T>` and check against the `IEnumerable` if order is important.

Comment: All of the methods in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.CollectionAssert` expect non-generic `ICollection` parameters, not `IEnumerable`. If that's what you're using, you need to give it `actual.ToList()`, and some equivalent sequence of ints that implements `ICollection`. `Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList()` would do it in this case.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett, if I use ToList then can I rely on the order when I do a CollectionsAssert?

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, ToList will preserve the order of the original sequence.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett, if the enumerable contains a count of zero then what is returned by ToList? i.e. what would I test for? Thank you.

Comment: Try it! Just returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ClassToTest c = new ClassToTest();

var expected = int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var actual = c.Numbers().ToArray();

CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think I will use ToList.  Will the order be correct after ToList is run?

Comment: @w0051977, ToList() will keep the elements in the same order as provided by (the enumerator of) the IEnumerable...

Comment: if the enumerable contains a count of zero then what is returned by ToList? i.e. what would I test for? Thank you.

Comment: @w0051977: It will create an empty list.